# Why does Chrome change tabId when I type new search into address bar and then it navigates me to google page results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've written the following simple code in my background script:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (info) {
    console.log(info.tabId);
});
```

Then I go and open new tab. Console logs `73`. Then I update the url of the opened tab, nothing is logged into the console. However, if I then type anything into the address bar on the same tab and google results page is open, the new id `77` is logged into the console.

What's happening here?

Comment: Not repro at my end...

Comment: @HaibaraAi, when you type 'landing` in the address bar and press `enter`, does it take you to google results page?

Comment: @HaibaraAi This may be dependent on "Instant search" setting being enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome prerenders omnibar search results while you type there. It uses a hidden internal tab with a tabId of -1 while it's hidden, then a new tabId is assigned if the user confirms the search via Enter/mouseclick. And this new tab with a new tabId entirely replaces the current tab.

Prerendered tab replacement event: [chrome.tabs.onReplaced](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onReplaced).

Prerendering may be disabled with a [command line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: thanks, do you know of any other case when the `tabId` can be changed?

Comment: I'll try to rephrase. It's not `tabId` that's changing, but the tab itself gets replaced with a *different* tab that has a different tabId, while the only case when the property itself can change is when it's assigned for the first and only time to that hidden prerendered tab (`-1` becomes an actual new value).

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I'm trying to bind my logic to tabId, and right now thinking if I may come across anything similar to the behavior described by your